# Multi-field Haystack form won't run unless q field has value...why?

Tags: django-forms, django-haystack

I don't understand why this happens. My haystack form has two fields, q and i_date. If you enter data in only i_date (ex. "1921-05-31") you get 0 results. If you enter data in both q and i_date you get results filtered by q and i_date. Why doesn't the search work with i_date alone????

forms.py:

```
q= forms.CharField(
    required=False
)

i_date=forms.DateField(
    required=False 
)

def search(self):
    sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()
    if self.cleaned_data['q']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = Clean(query))
    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['i_date']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(issue_date=self.data['i_date'])
    return sqs
```

I know the i_date search alone should return results because I ran the below search in the shell and got results:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(i_date=('1921-05-31'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I determined that haystack won't run a search unless the q field (main field) is defined in some way. Why I don't know. It must be tied to the way the built in SearchForm works. Anyway, to get past this problem in my case I used the following tweak to the above code:

```
def search(self):
    sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()
    if self.cleaned_data['q']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(content = Clean(query))
    else:
        sqs = SearchQuerySet()######this line is what fixed the problem

    if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['i_date']:
        sqs = sqs.filter(issue_date=self.data['i_date'])
    return sqs
```